# Changed from react native class to function and it doesnt work 100%

Tags: react-native, image, function, class, animation

I am trying to change a class into a function. This is mainly because if I can get it working, I want to use it for learning different animations, I have had some success but not 100%. Originally it displayed an icon that when clicked it spun it one way and then when clicked again it spun the other way. What I have tried to do it get rid of the icon and replace it with an image. It works when clicked once but then does nothing.

I am struggling with toggled aspect of it and setting the state I think because I cant seem to set it up properly in a function.

I have tried several things but this is the best I can get. If I show the original code and then what I have managed to change, maybe someone can point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong.

All I want is the image to display and then when clicked spins right and then if clicked again it spins left.

I am doing this so I can mess around with the settings and hopefully learn animation a bit better.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The original code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const TabIcon = ({
  onPress,
  menuToggled
}) => {
  const logoStyles = [styles.logoStyle];
  if (menuToggled !== null) {
    const animation = new Animated.Value(menuToggled ? 0 : 1);

    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: menuToggled ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();

    const rotateInterpolate = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
    });
    const animatedStyles = { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolate }] };
    logoStyles.push(animatedStyles);
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.tabStyle}
      onPress={onPress}
    >
      <Animated.View style={logoStyles}>
        
      
      <Animated.Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      /></Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuToggled: null
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { menuToggled: !prevState.menuToggled };
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TabIcon
          onPress={this.toggleMenu}
          menuToggled={this.state.menuToggled}
        />
        
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },  
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 100,
    margin: 8,
  },
});
```

and what I have changed so far :

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, Image, TouchableOpacity, Easing } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const App = () => {
const spinValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const [menuToggled, setMenuToggled] = useState([null]);



 toggleMenu = () => {
    setMenuToggled(menuToggled === "null" ? "menuToggled" : "null");
  }

const Spinner = ({
  onPress,
  menuToggled
}) => {
  const logoStyles = [styles.logoStyle];
 
    const animation = new Animated.Value(0);

  const go = () => {
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1500,
       easing: Easing.elastic(1),
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();

  }

    const rotateInterpolate = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
    });
    const animatedStyles = { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolate }] };
    logoStyles.push(animatedStyles);
 

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
     
      onPress={go}  
    >
      <Animated.View style={logoStyles}>
        
      
      <Animated.Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        }}
      /></Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
        <Spinner
          onPress={toggleMenu} 
          menuToggled={menuToggled}
          
        />
        
      </View>
  );
}






const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },  
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 100,
    margin: 8,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues. You first had menuToggled initialized to `[null]` when it should have been `null`. You also had forgotten to use onPress in `TabIcon`. The most noteworthy thing was wrapping `TabIcon` in a useCallback to prevent it from being recreated all the time. [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/i2lVS7sVV):

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const App = () => {
  const spinValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [menuToggled, setMenuToggled] = useState(null);

  const TabIcon = useCallback(({ onPress, menuToggled }) => {
    const logoStyles = [styles.logoStyle];
    // initialized base on menuToggled
    // if not done then it will take an additional button press to trigger
    // the animation
    const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(menuToggled ? 0 : 1)).current;

    const startAnimation = () => {
      Animated.timing(animation, {
        toValue: menuToggled ? 1 :0,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };

    const rotateInterpolate = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
    });
    const animatedStyles = { transform: [{ rotate: rotateInterpolate }] };
    logoStyles.push(animatedStyles);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          startAnimation();
          onPress?.();
        }}>
        <Animated.View style={logoStyles}>
          <Animated.Image
            style={styles.tinyLogo}
            source={{
              uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
            }}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  },[]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TabIcon
        onPress={() => setMenuToggled((prev) => !prev)}
        menuToggled={menuToggled}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 100,
    margin: 8,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do a icon rotation in a tab bar navigator. Im not sure the `TabIcon` component will tie nicely into the navigator. If it doesnt let me know

Comment: You a diamond, So i was not really doing that much wrong then? Where was the callback in the class version? And thank you.

Comment: In your class component you created `TabIcon` outside of the render function. I think if you move `TabIcon` outside of the component you wont need the useCallback

Comment: How do I do that? I was going to ask if its possible to do something like that so I could add this sort of thing to existing things like flatlists

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/kpsW6JW5W

Comment: Thanks for that but it spins around on an axis? On that new one have you moved the TabIcon outside the render now then?

Comment: I just noticed that the spin is off axis, but I think that is because its the View that is being rotated, and not the image itself. To overcome that you could just animated the image itself rather than the view. I worked out a flatlist demo as well https://snack.expo.dev/pzQokudmP

Comment: Wow, thankyou, that is amazing. A bit cheeky but I am trying to add a Bounce to it when clicked too, so it springs the image bigger and back whilst spinning. I have asked another question regarding this but you may had an idea already and thanks again mate.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/xd_y9v8rjE

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. It spins it on an axis again? The effect I am looking for is like a pulse or heart beat. Also instead of the predetermined image, how hard would it be to add different images from like randomuser.me and the information on there to the flatlist? Im not asking you to do this just is it possible and the whats the best way forward? Thanks

Comment: I sorted the spinning on axis out with this : const translateX = moveAnimValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
  });  I am looking forward to hearing what you think about that random image and profile bit! Thanks

Comment: Hi, I added the effect I was sort of looking for with this : const rotateAnimation = Animated.timing(rotateAnimValue, {
      toValue: newToggleVal ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 2500,
      easing: Easing.elastic(6),
      useNativeDriver: true,
    });               Thats what I was on about with getting this working so its easier to learn how to add things to animation.

Comment: It wouldnt be too hard. data would be created with the `useState` hook and initialized to an empty array. Then on component mount you would fetch the data from random user, format it as needed, and then setData to it

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/yBNx2iPZy

Comment: Thats brilliant mate, but what I meant was making the images provided from randomuser as the clickable icon. Your very talented and thanks for your help

Comment: For that you would have to have `SpinButton` accept a source prop. Then in the `Item` component you will need to have a images prop and create a piece of state to store the image index. On button presses you set the image index to a random number between 0 and images.length. Then set the source prop to `images[imageIndex]`

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/73dwdhEyq

Comment: Wow again, thanks mate, I had to take out setImageIndex(getRandomInt(0, images.length)); otherwise it changed the image once it has spun it first time. I am going to try and use this to see if I can add these to this project here : https://github.com/catalinmiron/react-native-movie-2.0-carousel  Before I do, will I encounter many problems and is it possible? Also I would like to animate a few other elements eventually but not sure if I should use reanimated, or LayoutAnimation. This is where I am getting confused between the 3! Thanks again

Comment: I dont know anything about layout animation, but I definitely prefer reanimated over the RN animated library. Im skimming the project, but I dont really see why you wouldnt be able to add waht you have

Comment: Hi, I want to use that because I want to add animations to the profile pic and then to the general layout like this https://dribbble.com/shots/8257559-Movie-2-0  If I can learn to make something like that or study the code that works then I would be a happy man. If you look at it, whats the best way to approach such a project. Also we are using animated on the this not reanimated. Whats the difference and would it make any difference to current project and is it easy to change over? Thanks agan

Comment: I think reanimated is built on top of react native reanimated. By default, every animation uses the native driver, and the animation values are doesnt need to be wrapped in a `useRef`. There's more stuff, I am sure, but I love the look and ease of reanimated. It might be more work converting to reanimated, and probably not worth the effort. Also, it is probably best to at least be familiar with the react native animated API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251148/discussion-between-phantomspooks-and-julesuk).

Comment: Hi PhantomSpooks, could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152867/problem-isolating-flatlist-item-to-animate please. I have sort of got the hang of the animations but can not incorprate into the FlatList like you did.